# Ansible facts not found when running tagged tasks

Tags: ansible

A pattern (or possible anti-pattern) I employ in my Ansible playbooks is to set some facts at the beginning of the playbook that the playbook will need.  The problem is that if I run only a particular tagged task, those facts are undefined and the playbook aborts:

```
- name: main.yml
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
      - set_fact: foo=bar

      - name: do something that uses 'foo' fact
        ...
        tags: [do-something]
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml -t do-something
```

Error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1] => One or more undefined variables : 'foo' is undefined
```

Can I declare facts in such a way that they will be visible when I execute only specific tagged tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`always` tag](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags) to the `set_fact` task:

```
- set_fact: foo=bar
  tags:
    - always
```